# Uncaught TypeError: 0 is read-only when sorting inside immer setter

Tags: reactjs, immer.js

I have some states like this:

```
let [state, setState] = useImmer({
    arr: [[], []],
})
```

and when I update the state like this:

```
  function update(result) {
    setState(draft => {
      let sortedResult = result.sort();
      draft.arr[0] = sortedResult;
    })
  }

...

update([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

then I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: 0 is read-only

but if I move the `sort()` out of `setState()` then it works:

```
  function update(result) {
    let sortedResult = result.sort();
    setState(draft => {
      draft.arr[0] = sortedResult;
    })
  }
```

Here `result` is just a plain number array. Why can't I use `sort()` inside `setState()`?